# Number toLocaleString not working on Angular' tests

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine

I have the following function on my application.

```
convertToPercent(number) {
  if (!number) return 'N/A';
    return Number(number / 100).toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'percent' 
  });
}
```

and then I just created the following test scenario

```
it('Should convertToPercent(10) return "10%" ' , () => { 
    expect(component.convertToPercent(10)).toEqual('10%');
})
```

But then When I'm running the tests it's broken because 0.1 is not equal to 10%.

Does anyone have some idea of what it can be?

When running the application it's working.

Comment: I've created a FakeComponent only containing your 'convertToPercent' function, and then a specific unit test file with your test scenario. Got a success. That's weird...

Comment: Can you told me what version of Angular and Jasmine you have there @JulienDéramond?

Comment: Angular 8.2.14 and Jasmine 3.4.0. Also successful with Angular 7.2.15 and Jasmine 3.3.1.

Comment: Since `number` is also a type, changing the method signature as follows may help: `convertToPercent(n: number): string {...}`

Comment: I did @uminder but it won't works either.

Comment: @JulienDéramond I'm with Angular 9.0.6, Karma 4.4.1 and Jasmine 3.5.0

Comment: First time I try to build something using Stackblitz so maybe I've made some mistakes but I think it is close to your environment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-63886733. It seems to be working with Angular 9.0.6, Karma 4.4.1 and Jasmine 3.5.0 no?

Comment: @JulienDéramond I  just discovered the problem... 
It was happening because I was using the phantom js to run... 
And then running the command inside the phantom browser I got 0.1 as the answer. 

So it isn't karma/jasmine problem, but the browser which I'm running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just detected that the problem was because the PhantomJS Browser as default won't support the ECMAScript Internationalization API as default.

To solve it you can install the `intl` library using `npm i intl --save-dev` and then enable it inside the polyfill file.

```
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import 'intl';

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/pt-BR';
```

Additional info: https://dzone.com/articles/using-phantomjs-with-karma